# We should [remove-if] useless

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [remove-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove-if) tag is talking about the "Common Lisp 'remove-if' function."<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/remove-if/info)</sup>.

In reality there exists only a [handful of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bremove-if%5D+lisp+is%3Aquestion) (at the time of writing 4), which actively talk about Lisp. The other [160 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bremove-if%5D+-lisp+is%3Aquestion) are all for different programming languages, including: Java, R, C#, C++, PHP, Python (the list goes on).

In my opinion: This tag should be removed entirely even when it is used correctly, it still is only targetting a *single* method of a programming language. And we clearly don't need a unique tag for *every* possible method / function for *every* programming language.

In short, remove the meta tag: [remove-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove-if)

---

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Kind of - It is as much useful in describing the contents as tagging the question with every method or keyword used in the code-snippet, the only thing we know without reading the question is that OP is trying to *remove* something with a condition.

Regarding the unambiguity one could argue that the tag is speaking for itself, also the operation of *remove-with-a-condition* is quite known across multiple programming languages. So it is used quite consistently across the questions I looked at.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes - It still is programming related, and asking a question about these sort of methods *can* be considered on-topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No - With or without the tag, we would still need to read the question, in order to find out what the OP is trying to remove and under what condition.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Kind of - Remove *something* but with a condition.

Comment: [remove-if] burnation is approved?

Comment: On the same line as @NathanOliver's suggested title: "Let's [remove-if] burnation is approved"? Or is it burnination?

Comment: _We should [remove-if] useless_

Comment: [remove-if] [considered harmful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful)?

Comment: I disagree with your assesment of 'Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?' - for people wanting to answer the question you are correct, they need to read the whole question anyway. But that's not all the SO is used for; when I encountered the remove-if idiom for the first time, I wanted to see some context usages and QA about it, so I could search on the tag to get that.

Answer (score -9):

The oldest questions with the tag all pertain to C++ (specifically the [`remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm), and the tag wiki was not created until several years later.

I propose that the tag wiki excerpt should be updated to be non-language specific:

> A method of removing objects from a container that meet a condition. Include this tag when you have a question about using the method, is it the appropriate method, if you need to use another method in combination with it (like an erase), or if you are having an issue writing the condition. Questions using this tag should also include the appropriate language tag(s).

The full wiki should also be changed to be language agnostic, and possibly include links to related documentation.

As part of the related cleanup, some questions should just have the tag removed (they use `remove`, not `remove_if`). There are also some questions are related to the C++ [erase-remove-idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erase-remove-idiom) and may need to have that tag added (possibly instead of [remove-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove-if).

Other similar tags: there is a [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) tag (with no wiki), and language specific tags [removeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removeclass), [removechild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removechild), [removeeventlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removeeventlistener) and [removeall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removeall) that may also need to be cleaned up.

Comment: Is there anything useful that this proposal brings? This is not a first come, first served, but tags needs to have a purpose for existing, not just existing for the sake of it.

Comment: @Braiam The same purpose as the tags [tag:array-filter], [tag:array-reduce] or [tag:map-function]: to categorise questions about these language-independent data manipulation functions.

Comment: @Bergi I think that your argument should be applied backwards: none of those should exist at all.

Comment: @Braiam Then what tags would be left? Only language tags?

Comment: @Bergi tags that are actually useful for categorizing topics into non-overlaping knowledge domains. Products are a good example of those. If a language/library tag generally covers all the functions, why have a tag for a specific function? We don't need to go that deep into categorization.

Comment: @Braiam I disagree. Only having language/library tags would lead to overly broad categorisation, many libraries are vast. We can and should go as deep as anyone deems useful (meaning: no more than 5 tags per questions, and no tags that would have to few questions in them).

Comment: @Bergi And the general consensus is that categorizing to the Nth degree is **not** useful except as an exercise in generating unnecessary tags. The likelihood of anyone watching a tag about a single specific library function is remote, whereas the likelihood of such a tag being incorrectly applied to unrelated questions is far higher.

Comment: @IanKemp I think the general consensus is that tag watching is not the only use case for tagging. Yes, one needs to make sure the tag name is specific enough so that it doesn't get mis-applied, but apart from that, no harm done.

Comment: We also have [tag:stream-compaction], which apparently gets used in some high-performance / optimization contexts, like CUDA.  (In CPU SIMD, I've usually seen it described as "[left-packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932240/avx2-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-pack-left-based-on-a-mask)" an array.) In the context of optimizing this algorithm with for different SIMD architectures, it makes a tiny bit of sense to have a tag for this.